# How do I clean up image thumbnail cache on 10.12 Sierra?

Tags: macos, filesystem, storage, folders

I want to know how to clean up image thumbnail cache on MacOS 10.12 Sierra.

Specifically:

The system cache (if any)

Cache for applications: XnView MP (if any)

Gimp (if any)

Now I understand none of them may actually exist, since MacOS, starting from Sierra, uses "dispersed" thumbnail storage scheme. but still, I just want to be sure.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Why is this cache a problem? A Safe Boot and then restart should clear most caches.

Comment: Hah, that's good news. I know very little about that system.

Comment: There is nothing "bad" about having caches.

Comment: I was clearly talking about having "left over data" in the cache.

Comment: Where did you mention this? What is "left over data"?